# Keep restriction toggles unchecked

Tags: outliner

I always uncheck the "disable in viewport" in the outliner. But if uncheck it and save the file, it keeps appearing every time I open blender again. Is there a way to keep that thing unchecked? Thanks!

[image: Restriction Toggles]

Comment: Can you add an image showing what you mean? - As far as I can see there is no option with the exact wording "disable in viewport" in the outliner that can be checked.

Comment: @JohnEason since around 3.0 "disable in viewport" is turned off in the filter menu by default. Its the monitor looking icon.

Comment: @RonJensen Yes. I have that option enabled, but I was actually looking for checkboxes! :^) Having just checked, Blend files do save the enabled state of each object between sessions and also the filter settings though so I'm not sure what's going on with the OP's system.

Comment: @John Eason sry guys, I forgot to upload the screenshot. I am turning this thing off every timesbut it keeps showing up when I open Blender.

Comment: Did you use File > Defaults > Save Startup File after you'd got the settings as you wanted them before closing Blender?